# How to disable button once it is clicked and enable it again once another button is clicked in android

Tags: android, button

My question is that how to disable button once it is clicked and enable it again once another button is clicked.
For example if there are 4 buttons when I click on button 1 it will be disabled and when I click on button 2 button 2 will be disabled and button 1 will be enabled again.

Currently I am using this code but it not enabling the buttons once it is clicked.

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListner = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn1) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
          // my code
         } else if (v == btn2) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
          // my code
        } else if (v == btn3) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
          // my code
        } else if (v == btn4) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
          // my code
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
// Create a global button variable
Button flagButton = null;

Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListner = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(flagButton == null)
            flagButton = (Button)v;
        else
            flagButton.setEnabled(true);

        v.setEnabled(false);
        flagButton = (Button)v;

        if (v == btn1)
          // my code
        else if (v == btn2)
          // my code
        else if (v == btn3)
          // my code
        else if (v == btn4)
          // my code
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use btn2.setEnabled(true);

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListner = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn1) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
                btn2.setEnabled(true);
                btn3.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
         } else if (v == btn2) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);

                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn3.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
        } else if (v == btn3) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);

                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn2.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
        } else if (v == btn4) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);

                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn3.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
        }
```

Comment: @Jois better delete and this because in this case you dont know exactly which buttons are disabled (if you got some flags yep but in this case you haven`t) and next time think before write some answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply setEnabled(true) for other buttons as below:

```
Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListner = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn1) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
                btn2.setEnabled(true);
                btn3.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
         } else if (v == btn2) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);

                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn3.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
        } else if (v == btn3) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);

                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn2.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
        } else if (v == btn4) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);

                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn3.setEnabled(true);
                btn4.setEnabled(true);
            }
          // my code
        }
```